# Adding a table to a PostgreSql logical publication

Tags: postgresql, replication

We recently created a new table in a postgres database and added it to a publication. Down stream only about 1/2 of the database need this new table. We created them in the desired databases and then populated the "master" table, but in the process it seem we broke replication in all of the databases where we didn't need or desire the table to be replicated to. The error we got was:

```
logical replication target relation "<schema_name>.<table_name>" does not exist
```

I verified that this table was not in the subscription with the following query:

```
SELECT s.subname AS subscription_name, c.relnamespace::regnamespace::text as table_schema, c.relname as table_name, 
rel.srsublsn, 
case rel.srsubstate when 'i' then 'initialized' when 'd' then 'copying' when 's' then 'synchronized' when 'r' then 'ready' end as state 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_subscription s 
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_subscription_rel rel ON rel.srsubid = s.oid 
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class c on c.oid = rel.srrelid;
```

My question is does a subscriber really have to have *every* table in a publication? Because this seem like a pretty major limitation (at least to me).

We are using PostgreSql 14

Comment: "Because this seem like a pretty major limitation"  You can have multiple publications, and pick and choose which ones you subscribe to.